# Candlesticks Color Values in Python don't apply

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, finance

I have the following Python code:

```
# Draw candlestick chart with colorup green and colordown red
candlestick_ochl(ax1, df_ohlc.values, width=5, colorup='g', colordown='r')
ax2.fill_between(df_volume.index.map(mdates.date2num), df_volume.values, 0)

plt.show()
```

The problem I have is, that the colordown value does not apply. I have set it to red (and I have also tried various notations) but it doesn't work. Interestingly the green colorup value works. The chart looks like this:

[Candlestick Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKWA6.png)

I am using mpl_finance.

Comment: Probably your data is in the wrong order. If your naming is consistent, you have ohlc data which you plot as ochl.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you! That was the right solution. I used candlesticks_ochl on an ohlc dataset!